# no idea why "label" popped up when I tap the cell table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: Before tapping the cell]

[image: After tapping the cell]

after I tap the cells
I don't understand why the word "label" keep popping up when I tap a cell in `UITableView`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = categories[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = normal_icons[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell?.imageView?.image = normal_icons[indexPath.row]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    cell?.imageView?.image = active_icons[indexPath.row]
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text =  " "
}
```

The table cell type is

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: What type of cell is the cell? If you used a storyboard, you probably set it up there (types: basic, subtitle, etc.)

Comment: Please also add code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

To

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Notice your did**Deselect**RowAtIndexPath and did**Select**RowAtIndexPath

But I believe there are more issues to it, even after changing didDeselect to didSelect

Comment: I updated the code above with didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Why are you using a custom cell? Your codes shows that you don't have a custom class. Try changing it to Basic and test.

Comment: remove the `cell!.detailedTextLabel?.text = " "` also. It is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the detailTextLabel in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath? That might be the problem. Try setting it to an empty string to confirm if that is indeed the problem.

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't work. I updated the code above with didSelectRowAtIndexPath